# Replace max and min values in data frame with existing values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, apply

I guess this is an easy task, but because I'm new to this world the problem is bigger for me.

I have this initial data.frame:

```
> df
      a    b     c
1 -0.05 0.31  0.62
2  0.78 0.25 -0.01
3  0.68 0.33 -0.04
4 -0.01 0.30  0.56
5  0.55 0.28 -0.03
```

What I want to do is to replace each maximum value and minimum value per row with other specific values.

So what I did is to create another data frame with new columns in order to use those as the "other specific values"

Here is the output:

```
df_2 <- df

df_2$Rep_MAX <- apply(df_2, 1, max) - 0.1
df_2$Rep_MIN <- apply(df_2, 1, min) + 0.1

print(df_2)
      a    b     c Rep_MAX Rep_MIN
1 -0.05 0.31  0.62    0.52    0.05
2  0.78 0.25 -0.01    0.68    0.09
3  0.68 0.33 -0.04    0.58    0.06
4 -0.01 0.30  0.56    0.46    0.09
5  0.55 0.28 -0.03    0.45    0.07
```

I want to set 'Rep_MAX' to each maximum row value, and 'Rep_MIN' to each minimum row value.

This is my desired output:

```
      a    b     c
1  0.05 0.31  0.52
2  0.68 0.25  0.09
3  0.58 0.33  0.06
4  0.09 0.30  0.46
5  0.45 0.28  0.07
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to find out the position of maximum and minimum value in each row and replace them:

```
# Find out the row and column index for maximum and minimum value
max_pos <- matrix(c(1:nrow(df), apply(df, 1, which.max)), ncol=2)
min_pos <- matrix(c(1:nrow(df), apply(df, 1, which.min)), ncol=2)
# Replace them
df[max_pos] <- df[max_pos] - 0.1
df[min_pos] <- df[min_pos] + 0.1
df
     a    b    c
1 0.05 0.31 0.52
2 0.68 0.25 0.09
3 0.58 0.33 0.06
4 0.09 0.30 0.46
5 0.45 0.28 0.07
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(-0.05, 0.78, 0.68, -0.01, 0.55), b = c(0.31, 
0.25, 0.33, 0.3, 0.28), c = c(0.62, -0.01, -0.04, 0.56, -0.03
)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: This is just what I wanted. Thank you! @JasonWang

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` to go through each row and replace the max and min values as appropriate, then repackage as a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(-0.05,0.78,0.68,-.01,0.55),
                 b=c(0.31,0.25,0.33,0.30,0.28),
                 c=c(0.62,-0.01,-0.04,0.56,-0.03))

df2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,function(r) {r[which.min(r)] <- r[which.min(r)]+0.1
                                               r[which.max(r)] <- r[which.max(r)]-0.1
                                               return(r)})))

df2
     a    b    c
1 0.05 0.31 0.52
2 0.68 0.25 0.09
3 0.58 0.33 0.06
4 0.09 0.30 0.46
5 0.45 0.28 0.07
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using vectorized `max.col` to find the column index for maximum value for each row (in the second case, we multiply by `-1` so the index will correspond to minimum value), `cbind` with the row index to get a `matrix` of row/column index which can be used to extract the values of the dataset and update it with either subtracting or adding 0.1

```
j1 <- cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df, 'first'))
j2 <- cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(-df, 'first'))
df[j1] <- df[j1]- 0.1
df[j2] <- df[j2] + 0.1
df
#    a    b    c
#1 0.05 0.31 0.52
#2 0.68 0.25 0.09
#3 0.58 0.33 0.06
#4 0.09 0.30 0.46
#5 0.45 0.28 0.07
```